# High order difference operator applied to 1/u

Tags: co.combinatorics, difference-equations, finite-differences

I need a formula for $\Delta^k \frac 1 u$, where $u(x)$ is a strictly positive function, $\Delta^k$ is the difference operator defined recursively as $\Delta^k=\Delta^1 \Delta^{k-1}$ and $\Delta^1 u(x)=u(x+h)-u(x)$, with $h$ fixed. It is trivial to get a recursive formula by expanding the identity $\Delta^k(u\cdot\frac 1 u)=0$ via the discrete Leibnitz' formula. Thus it should be easy to prove the formula by induction. But it is not easy to guess the correct expression.

I suspect the formula is known, although possibly not widely known (like the formula for the $k$-th derivative of $1/u$). Any pointers to existing literature would be appreciated.

EDIT: I suspect the question is not clearly stated, let me elaborate on what I have in mind. Denote by $u_j(x)=u(x+jh)$. Then the formula for $k=1$ is
$$
\Delta^1\frac1u=-
\frac{\Delta^1u}{uu_1}
$$
the formula for $k=2$ is
$$
\Delta^2\frac1u=
-\frac{\Delta^2u}{uu_2}
+\frac{2\Delta^1u_1\Delta^1u}{uu_1u_2}
$$
and so on. The pattern is clear and resembles (obviously) that for the derivatives of $1/u$.

Answer (score 2):

You can apply the [formula](http://mathonline.wikidot.com/higher-order-differences)
$$\Delta^p f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^p{p\choose k}(-1)^{p-k}f(x+k)$$
to $f(x)=1/u(x)$. Further simplification will need knowledge how $u(x)$ depends on $x$.
For example, if $u(x)=x$ one has
$$\Delta^p x^{-1}=\frac{(-1)^p \Gamma (p+1) \Gamma (x) }{\Gamma (p+x+1)}.$$
If $u(x)=x^2$ one has
$$\Delta^p x^{-2}=\frac{(-1)^p \Gamma (p+1) \Gamma (x) \bigl[\psi ^{(0)}(x)-\psi ^{(0)}(p+x+1)\bigr]}{\Gamma (p+x+1)},$$
and if $u(x)=x^3$ one has

<sub>$$\Delta^p x^{-3}=\frac{(-1)^p \Gamma (p+1) \Gamma (x) \left[\bigl(\psi ^{(0)}(x)-\psi ^{(0)}(p+x+1)\bigr)^2-\psi ^{(1)}(p+x+1)+\psi ^{(1)}(x)\right]}{2 \Gamma (p+x+1)}.$$</sub>

It may be possible to find the general formula for $u(x)=x^p$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The formula I need is similar to the formula for derivatives of $1/u$ and its general form is quite clear. It is in the spirit of the discrete Leibnitz formula for $\Delta^k(uv)$